# How to save model parameters into the attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

**The problem:**

I have a model with several input parameters (e.g. input_holesize, input_threshold etc.). The model creates a polygon layer as its final output. I would like to save the parameters into the attribute table for each feature in order to make the results more transparent. I use QGIS 3.16.7 on a Windows 10 system.

**Attempts of solution:**

I added another field calculator operation as another algorithm to my model. I wanted to use the function *parameter*, which seems quite straightforward (function example given in the field calculator: `parameter('BUFFER_SIZE') → 5.6`). I tried various variants (e.g. `parameter('input_threshold')` as well as `parameter(input_threshold)` and `parameter("input_threshold")` and `to_string(parameter('input_threshold'))`). For none of these functions the field calculator returns an error message, however, the output is allways an empty field.

Aparently I am using the wrong syntax, or the function is actually not what I need.

**My question:**

Does anyone know, how to write the input parameters of a model into the attribute table of the output layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`parameter`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#processing-functions) function is used to get input parameters of the current tool. So create an input in the model designer and then you can call it by @Description, Description being the name of the input.

1. Open the Model Designer and select a number input (I will call it Input Integer).
   [image: Inputs]
   [image]
2. Set the input that you defined befor  as the input of the tool you want to run (lets say a buffer and the input integer will be the distance).
   [image]
3. Now we add the field calculator and calculate a new field with `@inputinteger` expression.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate some more? I tried to call e.g. @input_threshold in the field calculator but still get an empty output.

Comment: Ok, I update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do not have this parameter in my field calculator. Which version of QGIS do you use? I updated my question with my current version.

Comment: 3.24.3-Tisler in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: According to the changelog this is a new feature in Version 3.24 and not available so far in the LTR-Version 3.22.